# Transform string to integer/float/numeric not working Python

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a string i = '0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1'
For some reason I cannot turn it into a numeric/float/integer.

Depending on the way I try it, I get errors like:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'

could not convert string to float: '0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1'
```

Are there any other possibilities to turn a string with numbers into a numerical type?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Depending on the way I try it".  Show us what you tried to produce each error and what is your desired result.

Comment: What number do you expect `"0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1"` to be converted into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a string into a list of integers by first splitting the string into a list. Next, use list comprehension to convert each string item into an integer.

```
s = '0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1'

l = [int(v) for v in s.split(", ")]
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```